# React JS that use a rest props and a variable

Tags: reactjs, react-props, children

I am trying to use a variable when I fetch a array of code to create my menu with the IDs.

Here is the beginning of my function

```
// Constants import - fixtures
import {dummyData, trendingData, COLORS, FONTS} from '../constants';


export default function ScrollXBar({
  secondary,
  setSecondary,
  COUNTRIES_ITEM_SIZE,
  primary,
  mainScrollX,
  database,
```

Here is where I create the Menu

```
        // Set Place
        setSecondary([
          {id: -1},
          ...dummyData.primary[position].secondary,
          {id: -2},
        ]);
      }}
```

I would like to remplace "dummyData" object by the variable "database" which is the name of another depending on what was passed in the component.

Comment: Yes, like "...database" I am having an error when I write the code like this. 

If this is the correct way to call the variable, the array that I pass in database that may be wrong?

Comment: dummy data:

```
export const primary = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'California',
    image: require('../assets/images/california/LosAngeles.png'),
    secondary: [
      {
        id: 1,
        subtitle: 'Chase',
```


...
const dummyData = {primary};

export default dummyData;

Comment: if I use ...database.primary.

I get with React Native

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'database.primary[position]')
```

Comment: export const primary = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'All',
    image: 'road',
    secondary: [
      {
        id: 1,
        subtitle: 'U-Haul Chaser',


...

const trendingData = {primary};

export default trendingData;

Comment: I passe trendingData in database

Then

 I import all the array with

import {dummyData, trendingData, COLORS, FONTS} from '../constants';


I log database and I get trendingData

 LOG  trendingData
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'database.primary[position]')

Comment: I did a sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-cloud-3wy2m?file=/src/components/ScrollXBar.js:1087-1138

Line 42, I would like to have it dynamic to select the correct object in the constants folder

Comment: Something like this `database === "trendingData" ? [...trendingData.primary[position].secondary] : [...dummyData.primary[position].secondary],`?

Comment: Your code would work. I was wondering if there was another way to do it without a if statement.

Comment: Well. I am not sure I just do an app to learn React Native. 

From the top of my head. At one point it may be like Top5, Trending, Lower price etc

Comment: See [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-dynamic-property-mp78f) (it doesn't use `if-else`, it uses dynamic object property). And read about [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/2873538).

Comment: Totally work. Thank you! You honestly saved me